# How to fill areas with color gradient in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a model which divides dots on XY plane into 2 parts: it returns a range of values `(0, -1)` for every input pair XY above the orange and below the blue line, between the lines it returns `(0, +1)`. How can I fill areas with color gradient according to these values? It should be very common thing to do but I didn't managed find anything more useful than `fill_between` function.

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the code you have used to create the plot so far?

Comment: How was `fill_between` deficient? How are the coordinates of the dots on your example plot related to the `range of values` you mentioned in the question?  You may need to provide more information in your question.

Comment: Do you have vectors/arrays/equations for the orange and blue lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a 2D array depending on your model values (named `z` in the code below). And then color the pixels using that z-value, making sure to set `vmin` and `vmax` symmetrically to make the central color mark the zero of your `z`. If the colors are too bright, an appropriate alpha can help to soften them.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 20
red_dots_x = np.concatenate([np.random.normal(0.5, 0.1, N), np.random.normal(-0.5, 0.1, N)])
red_dots_y = np.concatenate([np.random.normal(-0.5, 0.1, N), np.random.normal(0.5, 0.1, N)])
blue_dots_x = np.concatenate([np.random.normal(0.5, 0.1, N), np.random.normal(-0.5, 0.1, N)])
blue_dots_y = np.concatenate([np.random.normal(0.5, 0.1, N), np.random.normal(-0.5, 0.1, N)])

plt.plot(red_dots_x, red_dots_y, 'ro', ls='')
plt.plot(blue_dots_x, blue_dots_y, 'b*', ls='')

x0, x1 = plt.xlim()
y0, y1 = plt.ylim()
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(x0, x1, 10), np.linspace(y0, y1, 10))
z = abs(x - y) - 0.6
plt.imshow(z, cmap='bwr', vmin=-1, vmax=1, interpolation='bilinear', alpha=0.4,
           extent=[x0, x1, y0, y1], origin='lower')

plt.show()
```

[image: sample plot]

Comment: Thank you. Do you know is it possible to get window coordinates and place them instead of fixed filled area `np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)`?

Comment: I changed the code to make the area variable.  You might need to adapt the z-function when you change the area, but from your question I understood you already had a suitable z-function.

Comment: I meant how to get `x0, x1, y0, y1` from the plot which was plotted by `plt.plot(...` before. Just for the case when other dots with different coordinates are plotted to make gradient fill all the area.

Comment: I adapted the code to use the plot limits for the background image. It results in a similar image but more adjusted to the dots.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know `plt.xlim` does that.

Comment: I checked this: `plt.xlim()` returns `(0.0, 1.0)`, not (-1.0, 1.0)

Comment: You need to call it after creating the scatter plot, otherwise matplotlib has no idea about the data and uses the default 0,1

Comment: `z = abs(x - y) - 0.6` - where does the `.6` come from?

Comment: And did you choose `bilinear` because it *looked best* (trial and error) or for some other reason?

Comment: It's arbitrary. To get the white lines close to the example image. To simulate the "model" suggested in OP's question. Part of trying to create a minimal viable example.

Comment: Bilinear gives the best interpolation with few points assuming the z function is smooth enough. So bilinear is quite deliberate.